# Benchmarking an improved wheel sieve

Tags: c++, primes

I followed your answers for my last questions ([1st](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/279100/improved-sieve-of-eratosthenes) [2nd](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/279240/next-level-improved-sieve-of-eratosthenes)) and I came up with these new versions of my codes but I face some difficulties to measure the efficiency of my code, I use chrono library to determine the run time, and of course it does not give a full description of the efficiency of the code.

How can I do the benchmarking?

Are there any comments on the new versions of the codes?

```
/* 
This program generates all primes numbers up to a given limit where all multiples of 2, 3 and 5 are pre-eliminated.
They don't take any memory to be stored, or time to be eliminated.
It follows the concept of the wheel of prime numbers where 2, 3 and 5 are our basis
*/

#include <iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include <chrono>
#include<vector>
using namespace std::chrono;



void wheel_Sieve2(unsigned int Limit, unsigned int N, std::vector<char>& sieve)
{

     int position [8] = { -1 , 23, 19, 17, 13, 11, 7, 1 };

     unsigned int start[8][8] = { {0,6,10,12,16,18,22,28} ,  {0,4,6,10,12,16,22,24} ,
                                  {0,2,6,8,12,18,20,26}   ,  {0,4,6,10,16,18,24,28} ,
                                  {0,2,6,12,14,20,24,26}  ,  {0,4,10,12,18,22,24,28}, 
                                  {0,6,8,14,18,20,24,26}  ,  {0,2,8,12,14,18,20,24}  };
    
      for (unsigned int primes_order = 1; primes_order <= ceil((8 * (ceil((9 * floor(sqrt(N) / 3.0) - 8) / 10.0)) - 1) / 9.0); primes_order++)
    {
        unsigned int primes = 2 * (floor((3 * floor((10 * floor((9 * primes_order + 1) / 8.0) + 8) / 9.0) + 1) / 2.0)) + 1;

        unsigned int multiples_period = ceil((8 * (ceil((9 * floor(30 * primes  / 3.0) - 8) / 10.0)) - 1) / 9.0);

        unsigned int multiples_start = primes * primes;

        if (sieve[primes_order]==true)
        {
                for (unsigned int position_check = 0; position_check < 8; position_check++)
                {
                    if ((multiples_start + primes * position[position_check]) % 30 == 0)
                    {
                        for (unsigned int start_positions = 0; start_positions < 8; start_positions++)
                        {
                            unsigned int multiples_start_order = ceil((8 * (ceil((9 * floor( (multiples_start + primes * start[position_check][start_positions]) / 3.0) - 8) / 10.0)) - 1) / 9.0) ;
                           
                            for (unsigned int multiples_sieve = multiples_start_order; multiples_sieve < Limit; multiples_sieve += multiples_period)
                            {
                                sieve[multiples_sieve] = false; 
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int N = 0, Limit = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter limit : ";
    std::cin >> N;
    Limit = ceil((8 * (ceil((9 * floor(N / 3.0) - 8) / 10.0)) - 1) / 9.0);
    
    std::vector <char> sieve(Limit+1,true);

    auto start = steady_clock::now();

    wheel_Sieve2(Limit, N,sieve);

    auto stop = steady_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start);
    std::cout << "Run time is : " << duration.count() << std::endl;

    // printing primes.
       std::cout << " 2 3 5 ";
         for (unsigned int primes_order = 1; primes_order <= Limit; primes_order++)
             if (sieve[primes_order]==true)
                 std::cout << 2 * (floor((3 * floor((10 * floor((9 * primes_order + 1) / 8.0) + 8) / 9.0) + 1) / 2.0)) + 1 << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

```
/*
This program generates all primes numbers up to a given limit where all multiples of 2 and 3 are pre-eliminated.
They don't take any memory to be stored, or time to be eliminated.
It follows the concept of the wheel of prime numbers where 2 and 3 are our basis.
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono;


void Wheel_Sieve1(unsigned int Limit, unsigned int N, std::vector<char>& sieve)
{
    int position[2] = { 1, -1 };

    int start[2] =  { 2 , 4 } ;

    for (unsigned int primes_order = 1; primes_order <= sqrt(N) / 3 ; primes_order++)
    {
        if (sieve[primes_order] == true)
        {  

                unsigned int primes = 2 * (floor(((3 * primes_order) + 1) / 2.0)) + 1;

                unsigned int multiples_start = primes * primes ;

                unsigned int multiples_period = (6 * primes) / 3;

                for (unsigned int multiples_sieve = multiples_start/3; multiples_sieve < Limit; multiples_sieve += multiples_period)
                {
                    sieve[multiples_sieve] = false;
                }

                for (unsigned int position_check = 0; position_check < 2; position_check++)
                {
                    if ((multiples_start + primes * position[position_check]) % 6 == 0)
                    {                            
                            for (unsigned int multiples_sieve = (multiples_start + primes * start[position_check]) / 3; multiples_sieve < Limit; multiples_sieve += multiples_period)
                            {
                                sieve[multiples_sieve] = false;
                            }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int N = 0, Limit = 0;

    std::cout << "Enter limit : ";
    std::cin >> N;
    Limit = N / 3;

    std::vector<char> sieve(Limit, true);

    auto start = steady_clock::now();
  
    Wheel_Sieve1(Limit, N, sieve);

    auto stop = steady_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start);
    std::cout <<"Run time is : "<< duration.count() << std::endl;
  
    // printing primes
    std::cout <<"Prime numbers are :"<< "\n" << " 2 3 ";
    for (unsigned int prime_number = 1; prime_number < Limit; prime_number++)
        if (sieve[prime_number] == true)
            std::cout << 2 * (floor((3 * prime_number + 1) / 2.0)) + 1 << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Profile your code, that helps you find where you are spending the time in the code. This [stack overflow question discusses it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/how-do-i-profile-c-code-running-on-linux)